# PHP iterations in loop

Tags: php, loops, iteration

I've looked into this a bit already and know I'll be using a modulus, but am a bit stuck. I've got a set of links like so:

```
Link 1

Link 2

Link 3

Link 4 

Link 5
```

GAP

```
Link 1

Link 2

Link 3

Link 4 

Link 5
```

This continues over a long period. I'm wanting to extract Link 2 from each bit but can't really do it. So far I've got:

```
$counter = 0;
 foreach ($items as $item) {
   $counter++;
    if ($counter % 6 == 2)  { continue; }
  }
```

Any help is very welcome!

Comment: Does the loop start over after every gap, or is it continuous?

Comment: Same loop the whole time!

Comment: You want to extract the second item or `Link 2`?

Comment: Link 2 each time it appears

Comment: Can you `print_r($items)` and post part of its content here so we know what the data looks like?

Comment: I'll just show you what I'm trying to scrape! It's this page: http://www.scotcourts.gov.uk/current-business/court-rolls/sheriff-court I'm wanting to get the second link in each list.

Comment: So you don't want the second item, you want to find a particular term/link right?

Comment: I would rather see a `print_r($items)` , because I don't know what the data you have in your array looks like. The problem would be easier to solve that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a *exact* answer to your question, but you have specified in comment that the source of your array is a HTML page, so...

When we process a HTML/XML string, the best way is **ever** to use a parser, because through it we can have more flexibility and more correct results.

See this code:

```
$data = file_get_contents( 'http://www.scotcourts.gov.uk/current-business/court-rolls/sheriff-court' ) or die('ouch');

$dom = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(True);
$dom->loadHTML( $data );
libxml_use_internal_errors(False);

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

$result = array();
$query = '//div[@id="T60AE9CAF007_Col00"]/div/ul';
foreach( $xpath->query( $query ) as $row )
{
    $li = $xpath->query( './li/div/a', $row );
    $result[] = $li->item(1)->getAttribute( 'href' );
}
```

By this way, you can obtain all link ignoring gaps and *tricks*.

I have added `libxml_use_internal_errors(True)` to avoid warnings on html errors.
With the main `$query`, I retrieve all `<ul>` node in the `<div id="T60AE9CAF007_Col00">` (note that I don't know if this id if permanent of subject of changes, replace if with best attribute), then I process every node to search all `<li>` children and I add to array the `href` attribute of each second child.

I think the code if self explanatory, but if you have doubts, feel free to ask.

---

- See more about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- See more about [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

Comment: Hey, that works perfectly! Thanks! Dumb question, but how am I best extracting each url from the array given there's no proper key?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand

Comment: Sorry, was a bad question! I've managed to grab all the urls as I wanted from the array. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly.. you have one large array with all links?

```
$items = array(
"link1", 
"link2", 
"link3",
"link4",
"link5",
"gap",
"link2_1",
"link2_2",
"link2_3",
"link2_4",
"link2_5",
"gap2"
etc..
);
```

i suppose something like this would work:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
$counter++;
//When counter is 2.. do something.. (1 or 2, can't remember, a while since i worked with php)
if ($counter == 2)  { continue; }
//when gap is reached, reset counter, ( 5 or 6, can't remember..)
if ($counter == 6) { $counter = 0; } 
}
```